# How to run Cisco packet tracer via command line

Tags: command-line, cisco

I downloaded the Cisco Packet tracer .bin file from

http://www.mediafire.com/?r95gqy7n331ht8t

then typed the following command,

```
sudo sh PacketTracer533_i386_installer-deb.bin
```

that command installed the Cisco Packet tracer for me, but I am not getting any way to run it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The command to run Cisco Packet Tracer is `packettracer`

Comment: On running above command I get : "Command not found."

Comment: @Deb Sounds like it's not in your PATH. In that case you would need to go to the directory that contains the packettracer program, or follow the answer of New USer to run it from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The installer extract files to the path:

```
/usr/local/PacketTracer*/
```

The executable is:

```
/usr/local/PacketTracer*/bin/PacketTracer*
```

now you can make a soft link so you can run command directly in your terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/PacketTracer*/bin/PacketTracer* /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Hi @Maythux. In my situation, default installation, the packet is in /opt/pt not  in /usr. I will write that in my next answer, copy and paste from your solution. Then I will delete it if you edit your responce with that correction (and write something as comment on my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find where the installation program is located, enter in that directory then do:

```
./packettracer
```

in my situation is:

```
/opt/pt/./packettracer
```

As @Maythux say, to let you execute via bash directly, you can do a link in /usr/local/bin/

> The script executable is:
>
> ```
> /opt/pt/packettracer
> ```
>
> now you can make a soft link so you can run command directly in your
>   terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /opt/pt/packettracer /usr/local/bin/
> ```

or, simple, copy that file-script in your Desktop.

NB make it executable if isn't!